# ORM that supports Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, mono

I'm starting up a rather large-scale open source server project written in C# which targets both the MS.NET and Mono platforms. However, I realized that Mono only has limited support for LINQ to SQL, and no support for the Entity Framework at all.

Two ORMs I have considered are NHibernate and SubSonic. However, I have no idea how either will operate on Mono 2.8 (which is what I'm targeting).

So, can anyone recommend an ORM that will run on Mono 2.8, or happen to have used some of the aforementioned ORMs successfully under Mono?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mono supports:

- [NHibernate](http://wiki.nhibernate.org/display/NH/Home) - Free, open source, proven and tested.  Easy to configure.  My personal favorite.
- [db4o](http://www.mono-project.com/DB4O) - Free if you open-source your own project.  You have to license it for commercial apps.  Much less well-known than NHibernate.
- [siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/) - Available for Mono 2.4 and up. You have to pay $185 for a license, but the redistributable engine is royalty-free.

In choosing from this list, I'd suggest NHibernate.  Lots of help is available out there for it and it works fabulously.

Comment: I guess I'll give NHibernate a shot.

Answer (score 4):

Another very interesting one I have come across recently is [Vici CoolStorage](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home). It even supports Mono ([MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) specifically) on the iPhone.

Comment: I need to use the monotouch version if I develop on Mono right? Sadly the project doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @asrijaal - I am not sure what does not exist. CoolStorage still exists and in fact supports Windows Phone 7 as well. MonoTouch certainly exists as well and is evolving nicely. Perhaps there was some confusion when MonoTouch transferred from Novell to Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

You sure NHibernate doesn't work on Mono? You should be able to use the same Assemblies at Mono. Another option is to download it's source and compiling it. Check this page https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=951909&start=0

Comment: I'll test out NHibernate on Mono and see how it goes.