# ORM for Android in Mono

Tags: c#, android, orm, mono

I have recently moved to using Mono for Android development.  Previously I've done things in Java and used ORMLite after having seen this post:

[Is Hibernate an overkill for an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257374/is-hibernate-an-overkill-for-an-android-application)

I'm now looking for a C# alternative and found the following link which suggests [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

[ORM that supports Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025004/orm-that-supports-mono)

If Hibernate is overkill for Android though, I'm guessing NHibernate also is?  Can anyone suggest a C# alternative to ORMLite that is suitable for a mobile platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer in the library sqlite-net:

https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/

Only needs a couple of .cs files added to your project and it works (SQLite.cs and optionally SQLiteAsync.cs too).  Must remember to change the namespace after copy/pasting the files into a project though.